# Group associativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is this valid in a group? $a(bc)= (ac)b$ by regrouping. I want to do induction on $k$ for $a^k\,a^l= a^{(k+l)}$, but when I do the inductive step I will have to regroup it as asked in my question. Please can someone help verify this.

Comment: No, it is not true that $a(bc) = (ac) b$: This requires commutativity of the group. What *is* valid is that $a(bc) = (ab)c$, since this is just the definition of associativity.

Comment: Then to do induction on k, should i  change the order of the variables. To make it easier, because I am confused about the order.

Comment: See my EDIT in my answer below. It may be enough for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you know the group is abelian (commutative).

You have done more than regroup, you have changed the order. Associativity alone only tells you that $a(bc)=(ab)c$.

**EDIT:** However, it is true that all powers of a specific element commute amongst themselves, so you can indeed rearrange if the elements in question are powers of a single other element: $a^m a^n= a^n a^m$ for all $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

If your desire is to show that $a^k*a^\ell=a^{k+\ell}$, then you don’t need your superassociativity. As long as you don’t move one of your factors past another, you’re in good shape. And since $a^k$ is made up of $k$ identical factors of $a$, and $a^\ell$ is made up of $\ell$ identical factors of $a$, when you put one product next to the other, you just get $k+\ell$ identical factors of $a$, which is what $a^{k+\ell}$ is. This does not involve rearranging at all.